# Do solid state phased arrays need isolated power supplies?

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, radar, antenna-array

Non-isolated DC/DC supplies could have higher power density but it seems that high power solid state phased arrays utilize mostly isolated DC/DC converters to power each of their amplifiers.

Why are isolated topologies required for phased arrays like radars?

Comment: "*it seems that*" -- says who? Where has this been seen? Please provide examples. Then you assume "required", when at best a pattern has been observed; how can you justify such a conclusion, based on (as given) zero support?

Comment: @TimWilliams I am having a hard time finding too many published documents on this topic, but one example is "Realisation of DC-DC Converters for Active Phased
Array Radar Applications." They mention the need for isolation without going into details, and I have seen similar assumptions in other places.

Answer (score 1):

The power supplies we build for phased array systems (like airborn radars) all have their outputs isolated from the inputs.  These are almost always switched mode supplies with multiple outputs.  And some are very high power - multi kW.

But once in the system, that isolation usually goes away.  That's because most RF/microwave devices are, eventually, connected to chassis, through the shells of connectors or through the radiating elements.

So the primary power system (aircraft, satellite) return (the negative terminal, if you will) is connected to chassis, or structure.  Way at the other end of the system, at the aperture, the antenna elements are connected to chassis.

So to reiterate what I said above - the power supplies are required to have input/output isolation, but the system as a whole may not.

When I feel industrious, I'll put together a sketch.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  So if I understand it becomes a common-mode noise issue due to the ground connection on the output of the phased array?